# Use Outlook add-in token to get the current Item serverside with EWS Java API

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office365api, office-addins

I am building a Outlook add-in and I'm trying to 'download' the current selected Item (= mail message) with the EWS Java API using a login token. Next step is getting the attachments and process them in our system serverside.

I am following the [dev doc](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/item-data) where I use the `mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` method to retrieve a login token.
I'm posting this token to our server (that also services the add-in) and uses the EWS Java Api to fetch the current selected item.

But I'm unable to login with the token. The Exception I receive serverside is `The remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized`

In the add in token I'm using the following javascript code to call our service:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  // The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = function(reason){
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        getAccessToken();
    });
  };


  // Retrieves an acccess token
  function getAccessToken(){
      Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(exchangeTokenCallback);
  }

  function exchangeTokenCallback(asyncResult, userContext) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {

            // get info about selected mail message...
            var item = Office.cast.item.toItemRead(Office.context.mailbox.item);
            var email = Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress;
            var loginToken = asyncResult.value;


            $.ajax({
                  headers: {"X-Outlook-Token-For-EWS":loginToken,
                            "X-Outlook-EwsUrl":Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl,
                            "X-Outlook-ItemId": item.itemId
                  },
                  url: "/ac/api/email/ews"
                }).done(function(result) {

                    jQuery('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result));

                }).error(function(result) {

                    jQuery('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result));

                });

        } else {
            showToast("Error", "Could not get callback token: " + asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    };


})();
```

And the service is using this Java code to get the item (the `params` object contains the information I posted in the headers in the javascript above):

```
package nl.c2c.ac.api.service.email.outlookaddin;

import java.net.URI;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertySet;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.TokenCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.ItemId;
import nl.c2c.ac.exceptions.CustomException;

public class EmailOutlookAddinService {

    private EmailOutlookAddinParams params;

    public EmailOutlookAddinService(EmailOutlookAddinParams params){
        setParams(params);
    }

    public String retrieveMessage() throws Exception{
        ExchangeService service = null;
        try {


            TokenCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(params.getAccessToken());
            service = new ExchangeService();  
            service.setCredentials(credentials);
            service.setUrl(new URI(params.getEwsUrl()));  //new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")


            Item itm = service.bindToItem(new ItemId(params.getItemId()), PropertySet.getIdOnly());
            return "Subject: " + itm.getSubject();

        }catch(Throwable e){
            throw new CustomException(e);
        } finally {
            if(service!=null){
                service.close();
            }
        }


    }

    private void setParams(EmailOutlookAddinParams params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

I hope someone with more experience can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/284) the ews-java-api that pointed me in the right directly. I was incorrectly using the 'TokenCredentials' because it does not support OAuth logins. The ews java api has [not yet](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/288) complete support to login using a OAuth token. Fortunately we can pass http headers in the request, so this works for me:

```
service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + params.getAccessToken());
```

Along with this I no longer need to set the credentials with `setCredentials`method.